# Construct Binary Tree from Parent Array

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, binary-tree

This is a gfg probelm https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/construct-binary-tree-from-parent-array/1

My code is-

```
class newNode:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def inorder(root):
    if root:
        inorder(root.left)
        print(root.data)
        inorder(root.right)    

def bstfromarr(first,root,c,arr):

    if c not in arr:
        return
    if root is None:
        x = arr.index(c)
        root = newNode(x)
        if c == -1:
            first = root

        arr[x] = None 
        
      

    bstfromarr(first,root.left,x,arr)
    bstfromarr(first,root.right,x,arr)
    
    return first
    

arr = [-1,0,0,1,1,3,5]
first = (bstfromarr(None,None,-1,arr))
inorder(first)
```

Tree is constructed without any fault. The problem i am facing how should I return the root of this tree and print the inorder traversal of tree. On running the above tree I am getting only 0 as answer. Can anyone guide me
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the function `bstfromarr` isn't recursing properly, unfortunately.

In the two lines

```py
    bstfromarr(first, root.left, x, arr)
    bstfromarr(first, root.right, x, arr)
```

the "left" and "right" nodes are never getting assigned a value, so the two lines might as well always be:

```py
    bstfromarr(first, None, x, arr)
    bstfromarr(first, None, x, arr)
```

Comment: So how can I overcome this problem? Can you please guide me

Comment: First, just as a starting point, I think it'd make slightly more sense that `bstfromarr` simply takes a list (`arr`) and outputs a tree (specified by the root node of the tree, which is represented by a `newNode` object in your code).

Comment: Next, I'd work through some small examples. For example, what if `arr` has no elements? One? Two? That for me always helps me wrap my head around what my code is doing when trying to generalize. Hope that helps/makes sense, let me know if I can explain any better or help in some other way!